# How can I push footnotes to the bottom of the page in beamer?

Tags: beamer, footnotes

In beamer, footnotes appear at the bottom of the slide, but above the footline. However, the theme that I'm using has lots of empty space on the left side of the slide that would be perfect for showing these footnotes. Is there a way to position the footnotes in beamer such that the bottom of the lowest footnote is always at the bottom of the page?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  abc\footnote{\color{red}foo}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

That code produces this:

[image: normal output]

but I'd like to modify it to produce something more like this:

[image: output with footnote flush against bottom]

(it looks ugly in this case but that's just for demonstration purposes).

Comment: Footnotes are more or less connected to the text. By moving the text bottom you rip this connection apart. Even if the lines and color would match I'd have some issues in making the connection between the footnote mark and some text there where normally the institute or talk title is given.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how many footnote you have, you can use `textpos` to emulate a footnote like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}                    % new package
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\newenvironment{reference}[2]{                            %
  \begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(#1,#2)                   % This is the code
      \footnotesize\it\bgroup\color{white}}{\egroup       % for the emulated
  \end{textblock*}}                                       % footnote environment


\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}

  \begin{reference}{10mm}{93mm}                           % this is the code used inside a                      
  $^1$foo                                                 % frame to state the position 
  \end{reference}                                         %   of the footnote

  abc$^1$

 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces this:[image: emulated footnote]

knowing that a beamer slide is 128*96mm in size you can place text pretty much anywhere with this method.